# How do I display a git branch name, then either append a quotemark, or suppress newline?

Tags: git, branch

How do I get `git branch --show-current` to either stop appending a newline, or to insert a quotemark before the newline?
I want to create a C-style header file via something like

```
echo -n "#define GIT_LAST_HASH \"" >> TimestampNow.h
git log --no-show-signature -n 1 --format=%h%x22 >> TimestampNow.h # works well
echo -n "#define GIT_BRANCH \"" >> TimestampNow.h
git branch --show-current --format=%x22  >> TimestampNow.h # does not work
```

to create

```
#define GIT_LAST_HASH "1e3134d" // works fine
#define GIT_LAST_BRANCH "develop" // can neither insert quotemark, nor stop newline, at end of 'develop'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get what you want from `git branch --show-current`, but fortunately, you don't *need* to do that.  You're already using the shell, so just use it more effectively:

```
hash=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)
branch=$(git branch --show-current)  # empty for detached HEAD
printf '#define GIT_LAST_HASH "%s"\n#define GIT_BRANCH "%s"\n' $hash "$branch" >> TimestampNow.h
```

(Incidentally, most people find it's best to use `git describe`, rather than piecing things together like this, to make a printable string that can be used to describe a build.  Consider using `git describe --always --dirty` for instance.)

Comment: Brilliant. Exactly the result that I wanted. And that '-dirty' suffix is handy too; I hadn't considered that, but very useful.